# Custom OpenVPN client does not receive TLS ServerHello

Tags: python, ssl, scapy, openvpn

I'm writing a simple OpenVPN client (with Python & Scapy & [scapy-ssl_tls]
) which should connect to OpenVPN server.

I open UDP socket in Python and with Scapy I define my own OpenVPN layer on top of UDP (according to OpenVPN specs) and send packets on it (just like original client would).

I am able to successfully send initial `P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2` message and receive response from server, which is `P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2`, then I send `P_ACK_V1` message.

Keep in mind I generate all session ids correctly.

Now when I send first `P_CONTROL_V1` message, which is essentially TLS ClientHello on top of OpenVPN layer, I get a `P_ACK_V1` acknowledgement from server but that's it. Note that this ACK does only mean that server received OpenVPN message, not necessarily TLS data. I'm supposed to get ServerHello and all the remaining stuff but server does not send anything after ACK.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RBSV.png]

I compared the packet format and all network layers of my sent packet with communication of real client (image below) and pretty much all the fields are identical.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYTLU.png]

Wireshark combines and assembles packets automatically when it has the full handshake, so little tricky to compare it.

I also tried replaying complete ClientHello message from previous real client communication (I generated my own local time though) but results were the same - ACK and then nothing.

I also checked server logs and didn't find any errors or anything what could help me.

I create my TLS packet like this (with more options):

```
pack = openvpn(opcode=0x20, session_id=ses, message_packet_id_array_length=0, message_packet_id=0000)/TLSRecord()/TLSHandshake()/TLSClientHello()
```

`openvpn` is a layer I defined myself in Scapy.

Any ideas why I don't get ServerHello?

**EDIT: considering that I don't get any alerts from server I'm pretty sure server does not even see my ClientHello for some reason.**

Comment: could it be that your implementation only sends a `ClientHello` (first screenshot) and the 'real thing' consist of multiple fragments including `ClientHello` + `Certificate` + `ClientKeyExchange` + `CertificateVerify` ... (see screenshot info column and the 'message fragments' information)

Comment: In the 'real thing' client sends only `ClientHello` (which Wireshark splits into two `P_CONTROL_V1` messages), and then server sends it's own `ServerHello` and so on. Yes I have to send certificates and all that stuff, but only after server replies. I can observe this clearly with Wireshark when looking at real client-server communication - after ClientHello comes ServerHello. It's just Wireshark combines all Client messages even though they were sent in different order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `Message Packet-ID` must be 1 (or more). Now I get response from server.

[image]

[Official specification](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/security-overview.html) only mentions that Packet-id is for replay protection though..